# localhost redirect to specific folder according to the parameter passed

Tags: php, .htaccess, http, redirect, url-routing

I have WAMP Server, and inside the WWW folder I have two folders

```
1 ) App_A
2)  App_B
```

What I want is, if some one type the url http://localhost - It should redirect to App_B Folder, But if some one writes http://localhost/test, then I want to re-direct to App_A. How do I achieve that?

I have made the following code but not working...

```
<?php
if(empty($_GET['test'])) {
    header("http://localhost/App_A");
}
else {
    header("http://localhost/App_B");
}
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `.htaccess` file in your root directory, which is: `www` folder. Put the following content inside that `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://localhost/App_B [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^test$ http://localhost/App_A [L,R=301]
```

`.htaccess` is used for URL rewriting. In the code above, `/` is rewritten to `/App_B` and `/test` is rewritten to `/App_A`

Answer (score 2):

For the `$_GET['test']` variable to be set, the URL would have to be `http://localhost/?test`, not `http://localhost/test`. You can fix this by using .htaccess rules, as suggested above by *LIGHT*, or by using `http://localhost/?test` instead.